# Adding traces to d3.js animated bubble chart

Tags: d3.js, tween

I'm trying to build an animated time series chart which shows a 'trace' or snail trail following the moving dot. I have been trying to integrate KoGor's http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/8163022 but haven't had luck- I think the problem lies in tweenDash() - The original function was designed for a single trace- this one has one per company. 
Attached below is a working example- the time series scrubbing and movable data labels work, just not the trace aspect.

Thanks,

RL

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body bgcolor="#000000"> 
<title>BPS</title>
<style>

@import url(style.css);

#chart {
  margin-left: -40px;
  height: 506px;
  display:inline;
}

#buffer {
 width: 100px;
 height:506px;
 float:left;
}
text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;

}

.dot {
  stroke: #000;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.label {
  fill: #777;
}

.year.label {
  font: 900 125px "Helvetica Neue";
  fill: #ddd;
}

.year.label.active {
  fill: #aaa;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

</style>


<div>
<div id="buffer"></div><div id="chart"></div>
</div>


<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var source = '[{"name":"ABCD","AUM":[[2010,1000.6],[2011,1200.6],[2012,1300.1],[2013,1400.5],[2014,1600.0]],"AUA":[[2010,3000.6],[2011,3300.2],[2012,4000.0],[2013,4500.8],[2014,6000.3]],"marketPercentage":[[2010,40.4],[2011,39.7],[2012,38.5],[2013,37.1],[2014,36.5]],"fill":[[2010,0],[2011,-1],[2012,-1],[2013,-1],[2014,-1]],"xOffset":[[2010,5],[2011,5],[2012,5],[2013,5],[2014,5]],"yOffset":[[2010,-30],[2011,-20],[2012,-20],[2013,-20],[2014,-10]]},{"name":"EFGH","AUM":[[2010,32.8],[2011,43.2],[2012,58.3],[2013,78.8],[2014,92]],"AUA":[[2010,327.3],[2011,439.3],[2012,547.0],[2013,710.0],[2014,824.0]],"marketPercentage":[[2010,1.0],[2011,1.2],[2012,1.5],[2013,1.8],[2014,1.9]],"fill":[[2010,0],[2011,1],[2012,1],[2013,1],[2014,1]],"xOffset":[[2010,5],[2011,5],[2012,5],[2013,5],[2014,5]],"yOffset":[[2010,-10],[2011,-10],[2012,-10],[2013,-10],[2014,-10]]},{"name":"HIJK","AUM":[[2010,0.1],[2011,0.5],[2012,1.2],[2013,2.4],[2014,2.6]],"AUA":[[2010,159.6],[2011,176.7],[2012,199.9],[2013,235.1],[2014,269.0]],"marketPercentage":[[2010,0.1],[2011,0.1],[2012,0.1],[2013,0.1],[2014,0.1]],"fill":[[2010,0],[2011,0],[2012,0],[2013,1],[2014,1]],"xOffset":[[2010,5],[2011,5],[2012,5],[2013,5],[2014,5]],"yOffset":[[2010,-10],[2011,-10],[2012,-10],[2013,-10],[2014,-10]]}]';


// Various accessors that specify the four dimensions of data to visualize.
function x(d) { return d.AUM; }
function y(d) { return d.AUA; }
function xo(d) {return d.xOffset; }
function yo(d) {return d.yOffset; }
function radius(d) { return d.marketPercentage; }
function key(d) { return d.name; }

// Chart dimensions.


var margin = {top: 19.5, right: 19.5, bottom: 19.5, left: 39.5},
    width = 960 - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Various scales. These domains make assumptions of data, naturally.
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 2000]).range([0, width]),
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5000]).range([height, 0]),
    radiusScale = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([0, 500]).range([0, 40]),
    colorScale = d3.scale.category10();

// The x & y axes.
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom").scale(xScale).ticks(12, d3.format(",d")),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

// Create the SVG container and set the origin.
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Add the x-axis.
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
 .style("fill", "#FFFFFF")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the y-axis.
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
 .style("fill", "#FFFFFF")
    .call(yAxis);

// Add an x-axis label.
svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "x label")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
 .style("fill", "#FFFFFF") 
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr("y", height - 6);
    //.text("income per capita, inflation-adjusted (dollars)");

// Add a y-axis label.
svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y label")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .style("fill", "#FFFFFF") 

    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
 //   .text("life expectancy (years)")
  ;

// Add the year label; the value is set on transition.
var label = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "year label")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("y", height - 24)
    .attr("x", width)
    .text(2010);



//d3.json("investments_v04ANON.json", function(companies) {
 
companies = JSON.parse(source)

  // A bisector since many company's data is sparsely-defined.
  var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d[0]; });

  // Add a dot per company. Initialize the data at 2010, and set the colors.
  var dot = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "dots")
    .selectAll(".dot")
      .data(interpolateData(2010))
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
//      .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(color(d)); })
      .style("fill", function(d) {return colorScale(interpolateData(2010)) })
      .call(position)
      .sort(order);
   
   
  var lineTraces = svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "lineTrace")
  .selectAll(".traces")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("stroke", "grey")
  .data(interpolateData(2010));


   //yields a mouseover label - "title" precludes need for separate mouseover event.
//  dot.append("title")
//   .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
//.text(function(d) {return d.AUM});
   
var theLabel = svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "texts")
   .selectAll(".theLabel")
   .data(interpolateData(2010))
   .enter().append("text")
   .attr("class", "text")
   .text("hey")
   .call(position2);

  // Add an overlay for the year label.
  var box = label.node().getBBox();

  var overlay = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("x", box.x)
        .attr("y", box.y)
        .attr("width", box.width)
        .attr("height", box.height)
        .on("mouseover", enableInteraction);

  // Start a transition that interpolates the data based on year.
  svg.transition()
      .duration(30000)
      .ease("linear")
      .tween("year", tweenYear)
   .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
      .each("end", enableInteraction);

  // Positions the dots based on data.
function position(dot) {
    dot .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(x(d)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(y(d)); })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return radiusScale(radius(d)); })
  .style("fill", function(d) {return d.fill>0 ? "green" : "red"} );//{return d.fill});
  }
    

//function  from: http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/8163022
  function tweenDash() {
    var i = d3.interpolateString("0," + 5, 5 + "," + 5); // interpolation of stroke-dasharray style attr
 //   var l = path.node().getTotalLength();
//    var i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l); // interpolation of stroke-dasharray style attr
    
 return function(t) {
      var marker = d3.select(".dots");
//      var p = path.node().getPointAtLength(t * l);
      var p = lineTraces.node().getPointAtLength(t * 5);
      marker.attr("transform", "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")");//move marker
      return i(t);
    }
  }

 
function position2(theLabel) {
theLabel.attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(x(d)) + xo(d); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(y(d)) + yo(d); })
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .style("fill", "#FFFFFF")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name + ": AUM:" + Math.round(d.AUM) + ", AUA: " + Math.round(d.AUA) });//{return d.fill});
  }

  // Defines a sort order so that the smallest dots are drawn on top.
function order(a, b) {
    return radius(b) - radius(a);
  }

  // After the transition finishes, you can mouseover to change the year.
  function enableInteraction() {
    var yearScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([2010, 2014])
        .range([box.x + 10, box.x + box.width - 10])
        .clamp(true);

    // Cancel the current transition, if any.
    svg.transition().duration(0);

    overlay
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout)
        .on("mousemove", mousemove)
        .on("touchmove", mousemove);

    function mouseover() {
      label.classed("active", true);
   }

    function mouseout() {
      label.classed("active", true);
      label.classed("active", false);
    }

    function mousemove() {
      displayYear(yearScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]));
    }
  }

  // Tweens the entire chart by first tweening the year, and then the data.
  // For the interpolated data, the dots and label are redrawn.
  function tweenYear() {
    var year = d3.interpolateNumber(2010, 2014);
    return function(t) { displayYear(year(t)); };
  }

  // Updates the display to show the specified year.
  function displayYear(year) {
    dot.data(interpolateData(year), key).call(position).sort(order);
 theLabel.data(interpolateData(year), key).call(position2).sort(order);
    label.text(Math.round(year));
  }

  // Interpolates the dataset for the given (fractional) year.
  function interpolateData(year) {
    return companies.map(function(d) {
      return {
//  name: d.name + ": AUM:" + interpolateValues(d.AUM, year) + ", AUA: " + interpolateValues(d.AUA, year),
//  name: d.name + ": AUM:" + d.AUM + ", AUA: " + d.AUA, 
//        name: interpolateValues(d.AUM, year),
        name: d.name,
        AUM: interpolateValues(d.AUM, year),
        marketPercentage: interpolateValues(d.marketPercentage, year),
        AUA: interpolateValues(d.AUA, year),
  fill: interpolateValues(d.fill, year),
  xOffset: interpolateValues(d.xOffset, year),
  yOffset: interpolateValues(d.yOffset, year)
      };
    });
  }

  // Finds (and possibly interpolates) the value for the specified year.
  function interpolateValues(values, year) {
    var i = bisect.left(values, year, 0, values.length - 1),
        a = values[i];
    if (i > 0) {
      var b = values[i - 1],
          t = (year - a[0]) / (b[0] - a[0]);
      return a[1] * (1 - t) + b[1] * t;
    }
    return a[1];
  };
//});

</script>
```

Mark- the second version you built works very well. I'm now trying to address the individual line segments. I've added an attribute 'toggleSwitch' but the below code runs 1x and captures only the initial state of the object.

```
  var lineTraces = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll(".traces")
        .data([0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
        .enter()
        .append("path")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("stroke", "grey")
        .attr("class", "lineTrace")
        .attr("d", line)
        .each(function(d,i){
          d3.select(this)
            .datum([someData[i]])
            .attr("nothing", function(i) {console.log(i[0])})
              .attr("d", line)
              .style("stroke-dasharray", function(i) {return (i[0]["toggleSwitch"]<0 ? "0,0": "3,3")})
        });
```

console log, one per object:

```
Object { name: "TheName", Impact: 120, bubbleSize: 30.4, YoY: 11, toggleSwitch: 0, xOffset: 5, yOffset: -30 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you linked to had a pre-established path and then attrTweened the "stroke-dasharray" on it.  Your first problem is that you need to establish that path for each company.  Then you can tween it.

```
// set up a line to create the path
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xScale(x(d)); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(y(d)); })
  .interpolate("basis");

// for each company add the path
var lineTraces = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll(".traces")
  .attr("fill","red")
  .data([0,1,2]) // 3 companies
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("stroke", "grey")
  .attr("class", "lineTrace")
  .each(function(d,i){
     // get the line data and add path
     var lineData = [interpolateData(2010)[i],interpolateData(2011)[i],
                     interpolateData(2012)[i],interpolateData(2013)[i],interpolateData(2014)[i]];
      d3.select(this)
        .datum(lineData)
        .attr("d", line);
    });
```

Now set up the transitions on each path:

```
lineTraces.each(function(){
  var path = d3.select(this);
  path.transition()
    .duration(30000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
});
```

Where tweenDash is:

```
function tweenDash() {
  var l = lineTraces.node().getTotalLength();
  var i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l); // interpolation of stroke-dasharray style attr    
  return function(t) {
    var p = lineTraces.node().getPointAtLength(t);
    return i(t);
  }
}
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CxpFhS3uNRJeVFNnvBl3?p=preview).

You'll see it's not perfect, the timings are off.  If I get a bit more time, I'll try and come back and straighten it out.

**EDITS**

Gave this some thought last night and it dawned on me that there's an easier, more succinct way to add the trace.  Instead of pre-defining the path and then `attrTween`ing the "stroke-dasharray", just build the path as you go:

```
var someData = interpolateData(2010);
// add the paths like before
var lineTraces = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll(".traces")
  .data([0,1,2])
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("stroke", "grey")
  .attr("class", "lineTrace")
  .attr("d", line)
  .each(function(d,i){
    d3.select(this)
      .datum([someData[i]])
      .attr("d", line);
  });

// Tweens the entire chart by first tweening the year, and then the data.
// For the interpolated data, the dots and label are redrawn.
function tweenYear() {
  var year = d3.interpolateNumber(2010, 2014);
  // added "addTrace" function
  return function(t) { addTrace(year(t)); displayYear(year(t)); };
}

// append the data and draw the path
function addTrace(year){
  var thisData = interpolateData(year);
  lineTraces.each(function(d,i){
    var trace = d3.select(this);
    trace.datum().push(thisData[i]);
    trace.attr("d", line);
  });
}
```

This [produces much better results](http://plnkr.co/edit/isGEkCSJqk0sXQxzLx6t?p=preview).

Comment: @user1515373, see new answer

Comment: Mark this is really great work, apologies for taking so long to reply. I've only built out the first version, and reading the your commend for the second version, that's the direction I'd was thinking in- building the path along the way. I'm going to see if I can get it to 'erase' the path as the scrubber goes back in time next.

Comment: @user1515373, I'm confused.  You want the 2010 portion of the line to be dashed?

Comment: To make 'dashedness' a per object, per time period option. I'm getting closer- in addTrace() there's a tweened array of all line points.